# SharePoint Workflows (SPD) - approach to parse HTML from JSON into E-mail body

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

Any
I have this rich html column in my list, that I'm retrieving via REST/JSON.
Its html content is `<p>I'm into a paragraf</p><p>This is another paragraph</p>` like, to be appended the body of e-mail. Occurs that it prints it literally into the e-mail body.

Any approach on that?

Tks

Comment: what do u mean with "HTML Column"??

Comment: U maybe mean "Single line of text" Column

Comment: It was a multitext rich column. I've changed it to multitext plain text column and it worked

Comment: HTML Column = Enhanced Rich Text, Multiple lines of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in the solution, it was necessary to change the column to plain text, so the html code of it is rendered in the e-mail body.

[image]